# react-query with rules of hook broken error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am trying to extract my API calls using react-query into a reusable hook. The parameters I need to send to this hook are moduleName and value. For some reason, I get an error that I need to follow hooks rules.

Please advice.

This is my code:

```
export const useAutoSave = () => {
  const fetcher = useCallback(
    (
      moduleName: ISourceLoaderEditTabs,
      value: Partial<ISourceConfigurationEdit[ISourceLoaderEditTabs]>,
      saveUrl = '',
    ) => {
      const handleSaveSourceDetailsMutation = useMutation(
        (data: ISourceConfigurationEdit) =>
          saveUrl
            ? postSaveStageRaw(`${POST_SAVE_STAGE_RAW}?${saveUrl}`, data)
            : saveSourceDetails(data),
      );
      const sourceId = sessionStorage.getItem('sourceId');

      const sourceDetail = queryClient.getQueryData([
        'getSourcesDetail',
        Number(sourceId),
      ]);
      handleSaveSourceDetailsMutation.mutate(
        {
          ...(sourceDetail as ISourceConfigurationEdit),
          [moduleName]: {
            ...(sourceDetail as ISourceConfigurationEdit)[moduleName],
            ...value,
          },
        },
        {
          onSuccess: async (data) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(
              ['getSourcesDetail', Number(sourceId)],
              data,
            );
          },
        },
      );
    },
    [],
  );

  return [fetcher];
};
```

Then in my component I use it as

```
const [fetch] = useAutoSave();

fetch('abc', {
  name:'a2441918'
})
```

[image]

**Code snippet : Stackblitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q8uvse?file=src%2Fhooks.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot call `useMutation` inside `useCallback`. Also, you don't need to. `useMutation` returns one object with two functions - `mutate` and `mutateAsync`, that you can invoke when you want to call invoke your mutation. So your custom hook very likely should only return whatever `useMutation` returns. The fist argument to `useMutation` is the `mutateFn` - the function that is called when you invoke `mutate` or `mutateAsync`, and you can also pass one parameters object there:

```
const useAutoSave = () => {
  return useMutation(
   ({ moduleName, value, saveUrl }) => saveUrl
        ? postSaveStageRaw(`${POST_SAVE_STAGE_RAW}?${saveUrl}`, data)
        : saveSourceDetails(data),
  )
}
```

you can then invoke it via:

```
const { mutate } = useAutoSave()

<button onClick={() => {
  mutate({ moduleName: 'something, value: 'somethingElse' })
}}>Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue as it states in the error log - usage of `useMutation`

```js
const handleSaveSourceDetailsMutation = useMutation(
        (data: ISourceConfigurationEdit) =>
          saveUrl
            ? postSaveStageRaw(`${POST_SAVE_STAGE_RAW}?${saveUrl}`, data)
            : saveSourceDetails(data),
      );
```

This `useMutation` hook needs to be outside of the `useCallback`. This also means that the `saveUrl` and other params need to be refactored.

```js
export const useAutoSave = () => {
  const i_dont_know = useMutation(x,x,x,x); // hooks can't be called in regular functions 
}
```

Rules of hook for reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Comment: Tried that as well. Same error

Comment: thne you might need to post few lines for useMutation hook as well. the error states @ line 10.

Comment: UseMutation is from “react-query”

Comment: Noted. Not sure then. definitely u r breaking the hook rules in the posted code, if you corrected that one as i suggested, atleast that error should have been fixed.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q8uvse?file=src%2Fhooks.js This is my stackblitz with the changes you recommended

Comment: I found another issue in the App.js. you are breaking the rule of hook the same way. That's why it complains.

Comment: Can you provide me a fixed version please?

Comment: Thats quite a work, but I was able to mock some responses and I have incorporated mutations with custom mutations both : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kucnko?file=src/App.js   . Rest I leave it to you as it crosses the scope of the error/question.

Comment: Got it. So I do need to handle the whole mutation inside the component, righT? I was thinking that the mutation would be handled in the hook itself and I can just send in the data from many other components and the hook will take care of it

Comment: It depends. In your sample project, yes. The code I edited has two types of mutations - one generic mutate that provides default behaviro and another custom mutation where you can have different data with diff callback results. If it helped pls mark answer and further questions, please raise a new one.